# replace rules values in web.config file

Tags: web.config-transform

My web.config file is like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="GETDOCREDIRECT" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="xyz...."/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.azure.com" appendQueryString="false" 
    redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Server_URL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^xyz...../>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/"^xyz.....//>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

==============================

In the above example, URL can be changed based on the environments.. can anyone let me know how to change web.release.config file to replace those values(file&variable transformation) similar like appsettings and connection strings.

Comment: Actually for appsettings and connection string values in web.config file, i am adding the values which are varying based on environment in web.release.config file and also updating the pipeline variables accordingly and using file transform and replace tokens tasks in pipeline I able to deploy the corresponding values correctly.. Similarly is it possible to do for rules values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the entire rule using XDT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="GETDOCREDIRECT" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="xyz...."/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://prod.azure.com" appendQueryString="false" 
    redirectType="Permanent"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</configuration>
```

In this example, I'm replacing `dev.azure.com` with `prod.azure.com` as a theoretical example. Replacing the element is done by including the following attributes on the `rule` element you want to replace:

```
xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
```

That tells web.config transformations to replace the entire element with the element matching the value in the `name` attribute.

Source: [Web.config transformations - The definitive syntax guide](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-transformations-the-definitive-syntax-guide/)

Comment: Thanks much mate, it's worked as expected.

Comment: Great to hear that. You can consider marking it as the correct answer then :)